# MQL5 coding not run in real account

Tags: mql5

I have developed a Forex Bot and tested in demo account it worked fine. But I deployed in the real account its not working properly.

I don't know what is wrong. While searching on internet its seems broker scam. Why is it working on demo account but not in real account?

```
#include<Trade\Trade.mqh>
CTrade trade;

CTrade         m_trade; // Trades Info and Executions library
COrderInfo     m_order; //Library for Orders information
CPositionInfo  m_position; // Library for all position features and information

input double   lot=0.01;
input double   lots=0.02;


int EMA = iMA(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,_Period,200,MODE_EMA,PRICE_HIGH);

double TargetProfitPercentage = 5;


void OnTick()  // it works on every tick
  {
//---
   buyOrder();
   profitCalc();
  }

void buyOrder() // to place buy order
  {

//Get the Ask price
   double GBPUSDAsk = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble("GBPUSD",SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);

//Get the Ask price
   double EURUSDAsk = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble("EURUSD",SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);

//Get the Ask price
   double USDJPYAsk = NormalizeDouble(SymbolInfoDouble("USDJPY",SYMBOL_ASK),_Digits);

//if we have no Open positions
   if(PositionsTotal()==0)
     {
        {
         //Open buy position
         trade.Buy(lots,"USDJPY",USDJPYAsk,0,0,NULL);

         //Open buy position
         trade.Buy(lot,"GBPUSD",GBPUSDAsk,0,0,NULL);

         //Open buy position
         trade.Buy(lot,"EURUSD",EURUSDAsk,0,0,NULL);


        }
      Comment("BUY ORDER PLACED");
     }
  }

void profitCalc() // Profit calculations
  {

//if positions for this currency pair exists
   if(PositionSelect(_Symbol)==true)

      // loop all Open Positions until zero
      for(int i = PositionsTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
         //Calculate the Ticket number
         ulong PositionTicket = PositionGetTicket(i);

         //Calculate the Curremcy pair
         string PositionSymbol = PositionGetString(POSITION_SYMBOL);

         //Calculate the Openprice
         string PositionOpenPrice = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PRICE_OPEN);

         //Calculate the PositionProfit
         string PositionProfit = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_PROFIT);


         //Calculate the PositionSwap
         string PositionSwap = PositionGetDouble(POSITION_SWAP);

         //Calculate the currentposition Net profit
         string PositionNetProfit = PositionProfit+PositionSwap;

         //Get the account balance
         double Balance = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_BALANCE);

         //Get the Equity
         double Equity = AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_EQUITY);

         //Get Real profit
         double RealProfit =  Equity - Balance;


         //Get the Profit or Loss Percentage
         double CurrectProfitOrLossPercentage = RealProfit/Balance*100;


         if(PositionSymbol==_Symbol)
           {
            Comment(
               "PositionOpenPrice : ", PositionOpenPrice + "\n",
               "PositionProfit : ", PositionProfit + "\n",
               "PositionSwap : ", PositionSwap + "\n",
               "PositionNetProfit : ", PositionNetProfit + "\n",
               "Balance : ", Balance + "\n",
               "Equity : ", Equity + "\n",
               "RealProfit : ", RealProfit + "\n",
               "Currect Profit Or Loss Percentage :   ", CurrectProfitOrLossPercentage + "\n"
            );
           }
         if(CurrectProfitOrLossPercentage >  TargetProfitPercentage)
           {
            OrderClose();
            closePendingOrder();
           }
        }
  }

void OrderClose()  // To close the orders
  {
   for(int i = PositionsTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) // loop all Open Positions
      if(m_position.SelectByIndex(i))  // select a position
        {
         m_trade.PositionClose(m_position.Ticket()); // then delete it --period
        }
  }

void closePendingOrder()
  {
   for(int i = OrdersTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) // loop all orders available
      if(m_order.SelectByIndex(i))  // select an order
        {
         m_trade.OrderDelete(m_order.Ticket()); // delete it --Period

        }
  }
```

Comment: Please include better description of the problem. "Not working properly" is totally obscure. Also, if you have tried things to fix it, include those too.

Comment: No Actually above codes are working fine in demo account, but its not running in real account totally I am not sure about the issue.